# Memory allocation failure with pointers

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, mingw, bad-alloc

I have searched about the famous error of "std::bad_alloc" but I couldn't find any case like mine.
I've implemented a code in c++ (to be accurate: running in MinGW with Eclipse in Win 7 Prof.) and the code runs great for small number of class instances, but when the number of class instances reaches over 10509, the error from windows appears and then eclipse shows the 'std::bad_alloc' error. 
I am using "new" to build the new class instances and each class is needed two pointers and three variables of types "long int" , "string" and "int".
I can not deconstruct any instances build before because I need them as nodes later on to be evaluated on some other part of program. But, I have added class deconstructor anyway to class definitions and they set properly for sure. 
I am sure about when and by which command the program stops, which is exactly after constructing 10509 class instances right when trying to add the 10510th class instance.

So I am wondering if it is possible to extend the reserved memory to allocate new class instances or not?

The code is too long to be pasted here.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: please paste the code using pastebin.com if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You'll get more people looking now it is tagged with 'C++'. If you run out of memory, there are two main possibilities: (1) you don't have enough memory available, or (2) you went trampling out of bounds of allocated memory and confused the system. In the second case, you need a memory abuse detector; on Linux, I'd point you at [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/), but that's not available for Windows AFAIK. In the first case, you need to reduce the amount of memory allocated for each of the classes. Or increase the memory available.

Comment: Also note that if you ask a general question and can't post the details, then it is possible that your question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.  It may be 'too broad' or require answers that as 'opinion based'.

Comment: Note that while the canonical reason for std::bad_alloc being thrown is memory exhaustion, it can also happen if the data structures used by the heap have been corrupted (e.g. by wild memory overwrites), such that the heap's allocator function is fooled into thinking that memory cannot be allocated.  If that's the case, then solution would be to debug the code that executed before the bad_alloc was thrown, so that the heap data structures do not become corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the dynamic memory in which `new` works typically occupies all remaining available memory in your process. There's no way to extend it further. How much dynamic memory you had initially depends on how much non-dynamic data your program has. There's no way to say without knowing more about your program. By reducing the size of non-dynamic data you might effectively "extend" what will be available as dynamic memory.

Secondly, on platforms with virtual memory it is not really possible to "run out of memory" (assuming you have a healthy swap file). But you can run out of *process address space*. Again, if you run out of address space after allocating only `10509` objects, something else must be wrong.

Thirdly, `10509` looks like a really low number. So, if you run out of memory after allocating so few objects it probably means that the objects themselves are rather large. How large are your objects?

Fourthly, dynamic memory allocation errors might be triggered by heap corruption, meaning that allocation will fail even if there's technically plenty of free memory still left available. There's no way to say without knowing more about your code.